# How to cancel address comment by $writememb?

Tags: verilog, iverilog

When I use `$writememb` in Verilog to write contents in a memory to a text file, the result shows as below.  But, I don't need the address comment. How can I cancel the comment when using `$writememb`?  I use `iverilog` to compile my design.

```
// 0x00000000
00000000000000000000000000000001
00000000000000000000000000000010
00000000000000000000000000010100
00000000000000000000000000010000
00000000000000000000000000000100
00000000000000000000000000000011
11111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111100
00000000000000000000000000000100
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000001
11111111111111111111111111111000
11111111111111111111111111110000
00011111111111111111111111111111
00001111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111110
// 0x00000010
11111111111111111111111111111100
```

I want a result like this:

```
00000000000000000000000000000001
00000000000000000000000000000010
00000000000000000000000000010100
00000000000000000000000000010000
00000000000000000000000000000100
00000000000000000000000000000011
11111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111100
00000000000000000000000000000100
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000001
11111111111111111111111111111000
11111111111111111111111111110000
00011111111111111111111111111111
00001111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111110
11111111111111111111111111111100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 21.5 *Writing memory array data to a file*:

> The $writememb and $writememh system tasks can be used to dump memory
> array (see 7.4.4) contents to files that are readable by $readmemb and
> $readmemh , respectively.

The file contents that you get with the address comply with the standard since the addresses are inside comments (`//`).

This behavior seems to be unique to the `iverilog` simulator.  I don't see comments when I use `$writememb` with other simulators.

You can try to contact the `iverilog` developers to see if there is an option to disable comments.

Or, you can try using other simulators.

Or, you can write to an output file using `$fopen` and related functions.

Or, you can post-process the output files to remove the comments using your favorite software language.  If you are on a unix-like OS:

```
grep -v // file.txt > new.txt
```

Comment: Thank you！I use xsim，and  got expected results.